# Test flight could't load apps

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, app-store-connect, testflight

I'm trying to download my latest iOS build from TestFlight. But it's showing following message. I can't able to download the application on my iPhone device.

**Title**: Couldn't load Apps

**Message**: TestFlight Couldn't connect to iTunes Connect. Try again later.

**Button**: Try Again.

Also, I noticed following item.

1. I verified my iTunes connect expired date, it's perfect.
2. It's not working past 24 hours.

Please help us to resolve this issue.

Please refer attachment.

[image]

Comment: This could be a temporary issue on Apple's side. Wouldn't be the first time.

Comment: @bauerMusic Actually, I check this on another account it's work perfectly. And also this not temporary issue it's not working past 12 hours.

Comment: this is happening around the world for the last day.  See https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/101400

Comment: My testflight shows the same error. Currently this issue seems to be a global one.

Comment: @bvs Super...Nice catch...Thank you

Comment: I am also facing this issue. I tried by removing and adding a user but doesn't works.

Comment: Same thing happening here. Everyone should be filing radars, to get attention from Apple. Go to http://bugreport.apple.com, login with your developer account and submit a bug report.

Comment: is anyone got a solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

Couldn't Load Apps.

You need change the DNS for the wifi.
Settings-> WLAN -> connected Wifi -> Configure DNS -> Manual

Clean the DNS and add 8.8.4.4 or 8.8.8.8
Or you can change 223.5.5.5,114.114.114.114.

Comment: is it fixed your issue?